# Ошибка 0x887a0001 при смене режима D3D12

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, directx, dxgi

Проблемы со сменой режима D3D12, код взят отсюда https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/direct3d12/creating-a-basic-direct3d-12-component.

Добавил строку `swapChainDesc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;`

При нажатии ALT+ENTER приложение переходит в полноэкранный режим но сразу после этого `pSwapChain->Present(1, 0)` возвращает 0x887a0001.
Разрешение ровно 2560x1440, `AdjustWindowRect()` применяеться только для окна, при 1920x1080 тоже самое. Стиль окна `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`

Если же запустить приложение сразу в полноэкранном, `swapChainDesc.Windowed = false;`, все будет хорошо, но при переходе в оконный, нажатием ALT+ENTER, возвращаеться та же ошибка.

Почему возникает эта ошибка, и как её исправить?

Comment: Во *фрагментах* кода по ссылке нигде нет `AdjustWindowRect`. 0x887a0001 - это `DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL` Отлаживайте, что там не так идет, обращая особое внимание на отладочный слой dxgi / directx

Comment: Окно своё, речь была о том что размер буфера точно стандартный. Слышал о том что буфер надо обновлять перед тем как менять режим, но как? Может он отправляет в окно какие-то сообщения перед изменением режима?

Comment: Никакого "стандартного" размера буфера нет. Буфер естественно должен пересоздаваться каждый раз при изменении размера окна, которое при этом получает обычные в таких случаях события типа WM_SIZE. При этом не должно оставаться ссылок на предыдущий буфер.

Comment: [... you must call `ResizeBuffers` to realize a transition between full-screen mode and windowed mode; otherwise, your next call to the `IDXGISwapChain::Present` method fails.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiswapchain-resizebuffers#remarks)